# What devices are available to test WM_GESTURE and WM_TOUCH code on a desktop machine?

Tags: windows-7, touch, multi-touch, gesture-recognition

I'm writing some code to handle WM_GESTURE and WM_TOUCH events in Windows 7, but I can't figure out how to test it. I do my development in Boot Camp on a 17" Mac Book Pro.

So far, I have determined that the Boot Camp trackpad driver in Windows 7 does not generate those events, and this generic trackpad I found on [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002USHTWM) that claims to be 'multi-touch' works as advertised, but not by creating WM_GESTURE or WM_TOUCH events. I verified this by using Spy++ to report the events; nothing with the WM_GESTURE or WM_TOUCH value was reported.

What kind of hardware is supposed to generate these kinds of events? At this point, I'm assuming it's only for tablet or mobile (Windows CE) hardware, but I'd appreciate any other suggestions.

I suppose there's another way to approach this -- I want to get functionality similar to Cocoa's [NSResponder swipeWithGesture:] and related methods, which report back swipes, rotation, and other gestures on the trackpad. WM_GESTURE appears to be the equivalent on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other option, which would require only another physical mouse device to work with, and should get you at least 95% of the way there is the [Multi-Touch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) project, which can emulate up to 256 touch points using physical devices - thus the need for an extra mouse, or two since it can be awkward to simultaneously work with a mouse in one hand and trackpad with another.

Comment: I'm changing my vote here as I downloaded the multitouch vista project and am up and running. I even built a multi-touch 'table' out of a cardboard box, acrylic sheet, and a webcam, and am getting the events I need -- thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

There are several monitors out there supporting touch with Windows 7. For example: Acer T230H.

HTH

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to buy another monitor, though the Acer you mentioned is a pretty good price right now.

I'm also starting to think the Cocoa and Win32 APIs are doing different things, so maybe this isn't the right approach. I'll accept the answer for now, but if others want to add some ideas I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Wacom makes several touchpads that support multitouch; a particularly inexpensive version is the [Bamboo Touch](http://www.wacom.com/bamboo/bamboo_touch.php).  This gives you touch without having to buy another monitor - although it doesn't give that direct interaction feeling.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm a bit wary of buying another touchpad, but hopefully Wacom can tell me if their drivers generate the messages I'm looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately the Wacom Bamboo does not have full multitouch support, according to http://forum.cockos.com/archive/index.php/t-53388.html and http://gguuss.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/wacom-bamboo-pen-touch-review/. The latest Wacom drivers from July 15, 2010 don't appear to support it either.

I have approval to do the work now, so it looks like buying a monitor will end up being the solution.

Comment: Crap, you're right.  Wacom's FAQ (http://www.wacom.com.au/bamboo/faq/technology/) specifically mentions that they don't support the Windows 7 touch messages.  Sigh.